# How can I open a popup window from an iframe through javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you can open a new window in JavaScript with [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). It shouldn't matter whether the code originates from an iframe or not. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Hm... actually prior to asking I tried. And didn't succeed. Maybe I need to retry.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Actually it opened, but was instantly blocked by popup-blocker, that's why I didn't notice it. Is there anyway I can bypass popup-blocker? It's not for spam I'm trying to mimic RPXnow behavior for openid authorization.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272389/janrain-rpxnow-engage-https-rpxnow-com-bypasses-popup-blockers-how brings light to bypassing popup-blockers topic.