# Janrain RPXnow (Engage) (https://rpxnow.com/) bypasses popup-blockers... how?

Tags: nonblocking, popupwindow, rpxnow, janrain

Basically I need to open a login window in a popup, so that it doesn't get blocked by popup blocker. Similar to what Janrain does in it's [RPXnow solution](https://rpxnow.com/). How do they do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most pop-up blockers allow pop-ups that were triggered by a user action, e.g. clicking on one of the login links on the page you linked to.

So if you tie your login popup to a login button that the user has to click to open it then it ought to get past the blockers OK.

(or am I missing the point - were there other examples of popups you meant other than on their home page?)